# Continue reading console input after Ctrl+Z in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For a university assignment, from the console I need to be able to read in multiple lines until the user enters Ctrl+Z. That I have no issue with, my problem lies with me being unable to read anything in from System.in after that because it always throws a NoSuchElementException.

The following is the code that I am using for reading in the multiple lines, it was provided by the instructor and so I don't want to change it.

```
System.out.println("To terminate input, type the correct end-of-file indicator ");
System.out.println("when you are prompted to enter input.");
System.out.println("On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <ctrl> d");
System.out.println("On Windows type <ctrl> z");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (input.hasNext()) {
    //Processes input
    addFileIntoDirectory(input.nextLine());
}
```

I understand that this is caused by the Ctrl+Z which equates to an EOF marker, but I don't know how to move past it. No matter how many reads after it I do, regardless of if I have typed more to the console, I just instantly get back another NoSuchElementException.

I have tried having a separate scanner for the menu, closing the scanner above and opening a new one for the menu but neither works.

Is there a way to flush/purge System.in or to reset it?

Please let me know if you would like more details. I have kept the rest of the program vague as it is homework.

**EDIT 1:** Assignment says "The system provides a textual selection menu as follows, and
runs in loop." Which means the program is not to terminate on Ctrl+Z.

> 1. add files from user inputs
> 2. display the whole directory
> 3. display the size of directory
> 4. exit
>      Please give a selection [0-4]:

Comment: End of file is end-of-file, period. That stream has ended. It is an ex-stream. However, I think perhaps you're misinterpreting your assignment. You have not written what it was exactly. But I'm thinking that if you're supposed to have a menu and then a series of input and then back to the menu - then the `eof` should come as the end of the **program**, not the end of the inputs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That's what I would have liked, but the menu has an "Exit" option so I am led to believe this isn't the case.

Comment: Nevertheless, write the full and exact text of the assignment in your question. There are many possibilities of interpretation if we don't know the actual requirements...

Comment: Is that the full text? Then it doesn't say anything about Ctrl-Z. Perhaps you should ignore it. Or you should say what the full text of the assignment was. I'm still thinking you're misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:

```
if (!input.hasNext())
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The long answer is:

Below is code, with comments made for removing later, to demonstrate the problem as I understand it and solution.

Note this demo is intended to only *work* with integer and `^Z` inputs.

Copy out the code and save into file `HN.java` to compile.

Run the program and it will prompt **One**.  Enter integers to your heart's content and exit the loop by entering `^Z`.

**Two** will be displayed followed by the `NoSuchElementFound exception` in the question.  This is because the `^Z` *remains* in the Scanner object `input` and thereby fails on the `nextInt()` method.

The first inclination might be to use `hasNext()` to account for this.  So go ahead and uncomment `/*Comment1` and recompile and run again.

Now you avoid the exception, but the program blazes through to the end, skipping over the `nextInt()` originally intended.

So now, uncomment `/*Comment2`, recompile, and run again.  Now the program will wait at the **Two** prompt as intended.  If you enter an integer here, you will proceed to the **Three** prompt for another entry.

However, if you enter `^Z` at **Two**, again, the program skips the next input.  To correct this, uncomment `/*Comment3`, recompile, and run, and you will see the program works for all combos of integers and `^Z` at the various inputs.

Now, you might be wondering why I didn't just reuse the `!input.hasNext()` solution in `/*Comment3`.  Here's a demo why:

Put back the `/*Comment3` and uncomment the `/*Comment4`, compile and run again. The program works fine and dandy with a `^Z` input at the **Two** prompt, but if you enter an integer there, you'll see the system waiting for input, but there is no prompt **Three**!

This is because the integer you entered was used in the preceding `nextInt()` so when the program gets to the `hasNext()`, it stops and waits for input.

The lesson here is you use the `!input.hasNext()` when you KNOW you have a `^Z` *in queue* such as when it was used to escape the while loop in this program and the original poster's question.  Otherwise the else structure is better suited.

`hasNext()` is confusing to work with.  You have to keep in mind that if nothing is *in queue* the program will stop and wait for input at that point.  This may mess up your prompting if you're not careful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HN
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp = 0;

        System.out.println("One");

        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            temp = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Two");

        /*Comment2
        if(!input.hasNext()) input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Comment2*/

        /*Comment1
        if (input.hasNext())
        Comment1*/

        {   
            temp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%d\n", temp);
        }

        /*Comment3
        else input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Comment3*/

        /*Comment4
        if(!input.hasNext()) input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Comment4*/

        System.out.println("Three");

        if (input.hasNext()) 
        {   
            temp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%d\n", temp);
        }

        System.out.println("Four");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really poor answer... add a few words and some formatting.

Comment: To elaborate as requested:

Comment: The line above can be used to "get rid of" a ^Z in the Scanner object "input". Insert the line before the next read.  Note, however, that if there is no data at all, the Scanner object "input" will pause execution at this line and wait for input.

Comment: This turend into a really nice answer ;-)